# How to find row in dataframe in other dataframe and get 2 rows before and 2 rows after python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

```
dataframe1=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5],'x2':[5],'time':[12/7/2019  9:14]}) 

dataframe2=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5,3,4,6],'x2':[5,5,6,7],'time':[12/7/2019  
                         9:18,12/7/2019  9:14,12/7/2019  9:16,12/7/2019  9:17]})
```

from these two dataframes get row index when values matched in three columns of two dataframe , after getting index get 2 rows before index and 2 rows after index in new dataframe

Comment: kindly add expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), there is used before [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for avoid not lost original index and no parameter `on` for merge by all columns names (if necessary, be free add it).

Then is converted `index` to `idx` with join 2 index values before and after with [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for remove values outside original `dataframe2.index` and last select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
dataframe1=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5],'x2':[5],'time':['12/7/2019 9:14']}) 

dataframe2=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5,5,4,6],'x2':[5,5,6,7],
                         'time':['12/7/2019 9:18','12/7/2019 9:14',
                                 '12/7/2019 9:16','12/7/2019 9:17']}) 

print (dataframe1)
print (dataframe2)
   x1  x2            time
0   5   5  12/7/2019 9:18
1   5   5  12/7/2019 9:14 <- changed for match
2   4   6  12/7/2019 9:16
3   6   7  12/7/2019 9:17

idx = dataframe2.reset_index().merge(dataframe1).set_index('index').index
print (idx)
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64', name='index')

N = 2
s = [x for s, e in zip(idx-N,idx) for x in range(s, e+1)]
e = [x for s, e in zip(idx,idx+N) for x in range(s, e+1)]
idx = dataframe2.index.intersection(set(s+e))
print (idx)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')

df = dataframe2.loc[idx]
print (df)
   x1  x2            time
0   5   5  12/7/2019 9:18
1   5   5  12/7/2019 9:14
2   4   6  12/7/2019 9:16
3   6   7  12/7/2019 9:17
```

Comment: thanks!  other is ok , here is one problem in original data if i want to get 100 rows before matching row and 100 rows after matching row , including matching row , so in new df will be 201 rows

Comment: @Edward - edited answer with `N` for columns before and after, here `N = 2`